# How can I use integrate Google sign in with my existing users?

Tags: firebase-authentication, google-authentication

I'm pretty sure someone must have asked this question before but I haven't been able to find anything to help me figure this out.

I currently have a set of users in my database and have my own sign in authentication mechanism for them. I am now required to add on Google sign in for my users but I don't know how I can map users who sign in with Google to their existing accounts.

Your help will be much appreciated.

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to do that,if they are using gmail you can access the user object, but from the client side. Unfortunately you may have to ask them to link.
So what you need to do behind the scenes is to check if their regoistered emaill address is a gmail. Then ask them to link. Follow the tutorial on firabase to learn how to link multiple auth providers [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/account-linking)

```
    firebase.auth().currentUser.linkAndRetrieveDataWithCredential(credential).
              then(function(usercred) {
                   var user = usercred.user;
                   console.log("Account linking success", user);
                      }, 
              function(error) {
                    console.log("Account linking error", error);
      });
```